# Ifstream crashes program when opening file

Tags: c++, file, io, fstream, ifstream

I've narrowed my code down, and I found the source of the problem, it's when I open a file.
The file does exists, and I don't get any warning or errors when compiling.

```
int main(int argc, const char* args[]) 
{
    cout << "Wellcome" << endl;
    cout << args[1];
    ifstream exists(args[1]);
    if(!exists)
    {
        printf("FILE NOT FOUND");
        return 1;
    }
    exists.close();
    ifstream* in;
    in->open(args[1],ios::binary|ios::in);
    //do stuff
    in->close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use a pointer to an `ifstream`.  Let the class do its job by allocating it with automatic storage duration and read up on [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Answer (score 2):

You have created a pointer to an `ifstream` object, but you never allocated an `ifstream` for it to point to.  To fix this, consider just stack-allocating it:

```
ifstream in;
in.open(args[1],ios::binary|ios::in);
//do stuff
in.close();
```

In general, you usually don't need to dynamically allocate objects unless you want them to outlive the function that created them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well that made sense :) And it works. I'm not sure why I didn't think of that xD